# creating zip without recording root paths; programmatically

Tags: bash, shell, zip

suppose
i want to zip this dir
〔c:/Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/〕

and my i want the output dir to be
〔c:/Users/xah/xx2/〕

(my current dir could be anywhere. I'm calling zip in a elisp program)
so i do

```
zip -r c:/Users/xah/xx2/build-util.zip c:/Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/
```

then zip will record the full path like this

```
adding: Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/ (stored 0%)
adding: Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/.svn/ (stored 0%)
adding: Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/.svn/all-wcprops (deflated 56%)
...
```

i want the paths to simply start with build-util.

note: i'm calling zip in a program (elisp) and i cant or don't want to use any concept of envirenment variable.

Is this possible with some zip parameter?

Comment: AFAIK there is no tar's -C option for zip, so you'll need to change the current directory before executing it.

Comment: hmmm... `cd c:/Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs; zip ...`, this give relative path, is this what you need ? possible using elisp?

Comment: thanks. I think tokland answered it. I didn't want to cd to the dir first that's the problem.

Comment: oh... replace it to `tar`, and tar with `z` do the zip?

Comment: @ajreal: That's gzip, IIRC, and I'd be surprised if Windows supported that out of the box. (I suppose here one of the goals is to pack it in a way that is useful as part of setting up a new machine or a new user that doesn't have admin rights.)

Comment: Although .tar.gz is not supported by Windows out of the box it can be extracted by virtually all add-on Windows archivers, including WinZip and many free alternatives.

Comment: I'd say @ajreal's first suggestion - you can use `pushd`/`popd` if you're wary of `cd`ing there and back :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough, your best option may be to use jar from the Java JDK.

jar -cMf c:/Users/xah/xx2/build-util.zip -C c:/Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs/build-util/ .

the "-M" tells jar not to create a manifest file and the -C tells it to change directories before beginning zipping files up. The documentation I based this off of is here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: By the way, a Java jar archive is just a zip file with some manifest information.

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite bash functions is pushd, it saves the dirrectory you are currently in and moves you to the directory you specify. The reciprocal function is popd, it moves you back to the directory you were in before pushd.
For example you do

```
pushd c:/Users/xah/ErgoEmacs_Source/ergoemacs
zip -r c:/Users/xah/xx2/build-util.zip build-util/
popd
```

I think you wind up with what you want.